# Locking down a docker container

Tags: docker, security, owasp, docker-api

I'm currently creating a service to run third party docker images/containers.

As part of this process, I am locking the down the create-container configuration on my host, to reduce the risk of malicious/rogue behaviour.

Using the following the [owasp guide](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Docker_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html) and the [Docker API Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate) I've managed to mostly lock down the create-container configuration.

##### My question:

1. If the network for the container is disabled/`none`, would I need to disable Inter-Container Communication as well (to stop containers seeing each other)?

(and there any glaring omissions from this configuration?)

##### Create Configuration

> i.e. disable networking, limit logging, limit disk/memory/cpu/caps/ulimits, disable restart, lockdown rootfs

```json
{
  ... Image / Cmd / Env ...

  NetworkDisabled: true,
  HostConfig: {
    LogConfig: {
      Type: 'json-file',
      Config: { 'max-size': '1m', 'max-file': '1' }
    },
    NetworkMode: 'none',
    RestartPolicy: { Name: 'no' },
    Privileged: false,
    PublishAllPorts: false,
    IpcMode: 'none',
    CgroupnsMode: 'private',
    CpuPercent: 20,
    Memory: _1GB_IN_BYTES * 2,
    CapDrop: ['ALL'],
    CapAdd: ['CHOWN'],
    Ulimits: [
      { Name: 'nofile', Soft: 1024, Hard: 2048 },
      { Name: 'nproc', Soft: 128, Hard: 256 }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: I could not limit the disk usage (aka `StorageOpt: { size: '1G' }`), due to the following error:

> --storage-opt is supported only for overlay over xfs with 'pquota' mount option